# problem with zeek, specifically broker in python

Tags: python, broker, network-traffic, zeek

I'm new to zeek and want to get to grips with it.
here's what I'm doing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw3Fu.png)
what could be the problem?
I have zeek installed and working.
I also tried this:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/zeek/broker
cd broker
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But nothing works